# Covariate significantly different among groups

Tags: anova, ancova

I ran a 3-way ANCOVA with the covariate "depression level" (independent variable is anxiety level divided categorically as low/high).
However, halfway throughout the analyses I noticed that including depression as a covariate substantially changes my results, even the direction of the effect.

I realized covariates are meant to randomly occur among individuals. Since anxiety is known to significantly co-occur with depression, including depression as a covariate may alter results, probably in a non-preferable way. However, previous studies do indicate that the dependent variable I'm measuring can also be affected by depression. Is there any way to control for the depression levels so I can only look at the effects of anxiety? Should I be running something other than ANOVA? My short statistics knowledge got me lost. Any comment or opinion would be immensely helpful.

Comment: What is the dependent variable ? *covariates are meant to randomly occur among individuals*. This is not true. If it was, there would be no point including such covariates.

Comment: This simply means that anxiety and depression are colinear variables, you might search this site for multicolinearity